# How to Find values with Only No

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an dataset like this where A,B are one set and C,D,E are another set.

[image]

I want to Filter out data where all the entries are **Yes**.For e.g. Only C,D,E should be returned not B.

Comment: How do you define the sets.  Do you just *know* what rows are part of a group?

Comment: What is the name of the table, what are the names and types of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you want filter then you can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.status = 'no');
```